# Make entire CSS sheet !important

Tags: css, stylesheet

Is there a way to make an entire CSS Style sheet take precedence over another? I know you can do the !important but can I do that with one line rather than modify all thousand properties on the sheet?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really, but if you explain why you'd want to do this someone might have some other ideas for you.

Comment: putting the stylesheet after others in the flow of the page download renders the stylesheet more "important" than the others, purely by nature of Cascading Styles.

Comment: In general, `!important` is a crappy way to write CSS.

Comment: Yeah, generally there are much better ways of accomplishing whatever it is you're trying to accomplish -- more details, please!

Comment: This question is *cringeworthy*. There's probably a simple fix you're overlooking. Explain, in detail, why you need to do this and somebody will help you out.

Comment: This is a useful question to anyone using Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: I have a mobile style sheet, it is called after the main style sheet, and I keep having to add important to various elements.  Not sure why the entire sheet doesn't overtake the preceding one, it may have to do with iframes, but the question sure makes sense to me!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure the stylesheet you want is called last (or a specific style you want is called last). For example, using this:

```css
span { color: red; }
span { color: blue; }
```

...will turn all text in `<span>`'s blue. Take a look [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Shaz/4nrDU/1/).

Comment: You are perfectly right but if in some other file you have span { color: red !important;} your last call span { color: blue; } is useless

Comment: but if the hosting site has an !important it won't work. (eg when you inject your CSs in another website)

Answer (score 9):

Rules with identical specificity that come later will overrule previous ones, so if both style sheets contain the identical selectors, you should be able to do this by just loading the one before the other.

If they contain different selectors, like

```css
#navigation h3 { color: red }
```

and

```css
.mainpage .navmenu h3 { color: blue }
```

you are likely to get specificity conflicts. The only blanket solution for that is indeed `!important` (although that is really, really terrible architecturally. Are you sure you need this? Maybe explain why, it's possible somebody is able to come up with a better solution.)

There is, however, no single-line directive to elevate the "importance" of one style sheet over the other.

Comment: I know it's sloppy. I am just combining some things and I hate to sift through a thousand lines of css styling to match whats colliding with each other.

Comment: @JD Hmm, you may be able to do a quick search + replace `;` => `!important;`