# How to apply !important dynamically via CSS

Tags: html, css

How can we apply `!important` to a rule dynamically via CSS?

Let's say we have many (1000+) utility classes:

```css
.text-align-left   { text-align: left   }
.text-align-right  { text-align: right  }
.text-align-center { text-align: center }
```

Now, instead of adding `!important` to every utility class, how can we apply it dynamically? Like the "override" class below in which we are just adding `!important`:

```css
.class-to-override.override { rule: def !important }
```

Comment: Why do you need so many layers of overrides? Especially if you’re already using lots of little utility classes like this, there should be no need for overrides at all

Comment: idk @MTCoster sometimes using 3rd party libraries are asking for it. Bootstrap for example, I've found some scenarios in Bootstrap 3 that just need an `!important` value

Comment: Let's assume i am making a css framework. How can i add a "generic" class which will increase the "specificity" to the highest ?

Comment: Ever thought about BEM (http://getbem.com/)? No need for `!important` anymore.

Comment: Honestly, and this is purely opinionated, I just don't see what advantage you have when using `.class-to-override.override` it's just as much typing as `.class-plus-important`. The only argument I see is you wanting to condense it to a 1 liner. The only obstacle you have, with a pure CSS solution, is there is just no way to know what property/rule is set to override this way.

Comment: Also another thing you should consider, is if an element has more than 1 utility class, which one does `.override` target? All of them? One of them?

Comment: You can try putting all the important styles in one stylesheet and including it after your original stylesheet, it will help but that wont guarantee override of all styles. Otherwise there is no single way to make a selection of styles !important without doing it manually. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526510/make-entire-css-sheet-important)

Comment: Outside of what’s been said, I can say with confidence _please_ reconsider the important overrides. There are better ways to approach it. I handled a repo with nothing but important tags and it’s  _rough_. If you have the ability to modify the codebase, please do.  Css is a _cascading language_ so there are many options at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very old question, but I'll give it a shot:

`CSS` and `dynamically` are not *best friends*, so the short answer would be: **you can't** append the `!important` keyword to the end of the rule, dynamically in CSS.

Although you could increase the specificity by doubling the selector: `.text-align-left.text-align-left` instead of just `.text-align-left` (working and allowed according to the W3 documentation: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity ), I don't think it will help a lot in this case.

Your best option might be to create a new set of helper classes, and use them only where needed.

```
.text-align-left-i {text-align: left !important;}
```